# Remote logs from rsyslog appear in general logfiles

Tags: rsyslog

I've set up rsyslog (according to guides [like this](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/configuring-remote-logging-using-rsyslog-in-centos-rhel/)) to ingest remote logs via the following general configuration:

```
module(load="imudp")
input(type="imudp" port="514")

module(load="imtcp")
input(type="imtcp" port="514")

module(load="imklog" permitnonkernelfacility="on")

$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

$RepeatedMsgReduction on

$FileOwner syslog
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022
$PrivDropToUser syslog
$PrivDropToGroup syslog

$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog

$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
```

Additionally, I've created the file `/etc/rsyslog.d/remote.conf` with those contents:

```
$template RemoteLogs,"/mnt/monitoring-logs/logs/%HOSTNAME%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log"
*.* ?RemoteLogs

$template HostAudit, "/mnt/monitoring-logs/logs/%HOSTNAME%/audit.log"
local6.* ?HostAudit

& ~
```

This works in the sense that it creates the respective hostname directories and specific logs. However, I also see all logs duplicated in my local host's logfiles (in `/var/log`). For instance, `/var/log/syslog` contains messages not only from the monitoring server's host, but also all other remote hosts.

How can I prevent this type of duplication? I'd only like to see the messages from the host itself being logged to the default log files.

I guess I need some way to stop forwarding these specific remote logs. Looking at [the documentation](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/concepts/multi_ruleset.html) (which I found from the link in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/837010/rsyslog-logs-are-beeing-duplicated/837568#837568)) I noted there is a way to add a ruleset, so I changed my general config to this:

```
ruleset(name="remote") {
  action(type="omfile" file="/mnt/monitoring-logs/logs/%HOSTNAME%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log")
  stop
}

# ...

input(type="imudp" port="514" ruleset="remote")
input(type="imtcp" port="514" ruleset="remote")
```

This made it stop ingesting remote logs to the general logfiles, but it also made it stop writing the output to the dedicated `/mnt/monitoring-logs` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it with a combination of the two. The final, full config is like this:

```
ruleset(name="remote") {
  $template RemoteLogs,"/mnt/monitoring-logs/logs/%HOSTNAME%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log"
  *.* ?RemoteLogs

  $template HostAudit, "/mnt/monitoring-logs/logs/%HOSTNAME%/audit.log"
  local6.* ?HostAudit

  stop
}

module(load="imudp")
input(type="imudp" port="514" ruleset="remote")

module(load="imtcp")
input(type="imtcp" port="514" ruleset="remote")

module(load="imklog" permitnonkernelfacility="on")

$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

$RepeatedMsgReduction on

$FileOwner syslog
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022
$PrivDropToUser syslog
$PrivDropToGroup syslog

$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog

$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
```

Note that there is now no specific `remote.conf` file in the `/etc/rsyslog.d/` folder.